# Using numpy.cov on a vector yields NANs

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

Good afternoon.

I am faced with a PCA task which simply involves reducing the dimensionality of a vector. I'm not interested in a two-dimensional matrix in this case, but merely a D-dimensional vector which I would like to project along it's K principal eigenvectors.

In order to implement PCA, I need to retrieve the covariance matrix of this vector. Let's try to do this on an example vector:

```
someVec = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, -1.0]])
```

I've defined this vector as a 1 X 4 matrix, i.e a row vector, in order to make it compatible with numpy.cov. Taking the covariance matrix of this vector through numpy.cov will yield a scalar covariance matrix, because numpy.cov makes the assumption that the features are in the rows:

```
print np.cov(someVec)
1.58333333333
```

but this is (or rather, should be) merely a difference in dimensionality assumptions, and taking the covariance of the transpose vector should work fine, right? Except that it doesn't:

```
print np.cov(someVec.T)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2005: RuntimeWarning:                  
invalid value encountered in divide
return (dot(X, X.T.conj()) / fact).squeeze()
[[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong here. Any advice?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Just to be clear, you are expecting `np.cov(someVec.T)` to also return a scalar?

Comment: Not really, shouldn't that be returning a matrix of size 4 x 4? I mean, the vector has 4 "features", so given that I want to measure the variance between the features and store them in appropriate places (for example, cov(1, 3), I need a covariance matrix, do I not?

Comment: If you a single D-dimensional vector you can reduce its dimensionality by removing the smallest component vectors. Eg [1,3,2,.001] => [1,3,2], of course you should normalize your vector before and after. Milage may vary.

Comment: Apologies, but what would you exactly mean by "milage", in this case?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing, if all components have equal weight then this is fairly valid. If not you will run into trouble.

Comment: I'd like to thank everybody, my teammates assured me that I will be receiving more examples than the single one originally anticipated; it appears therefore that I can do PCA over those examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass in the transpose, you'll need to set `rowvar` to zero.

```
In [10]: np.cov(someVec, rowvar=0)
Out[10]: array(1.5833333333333333)

In [11]: np.cov(someVec.T, rowvar=0)
Out[11]: array(1.5833333333333333)
```

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html):

> **rowvar** : int, optional
>
> If rowvar is non-zero (default), then each row
>   represents a variable, with observations in the columns. Otherwise,
>   the relationship is transposed: each column represents a variable,
>   while the rows contain observations.

If you want to find a full covariance matrix, you'll need more than one observation. With a single observation, and numpy's default estimator, `NaN` is exactly what you'd expect. If you would like to have normalization done by `N` instead of `(N-1)`, you can pass in a `1` to the bias.

```
In [12]: np.cov(someVec.T, bias=1)
Out[12]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Again, from the docs.

> **bias** : int, optional
>
> Default normalization is by (N - 1), where N is
>   the number of observations given (unbiased estimate). If bias is 1,
>   then normalization is by N. These values can be overridden by using
>   the keyword ddof in numpy versions >= 1.5.

Comment: Thank you, but this still returns a scalar, while what I need is a full-blown covariance matrix. See my response to NPE's comment above.

Comment: Okay, it would have been good to make that clear in your question. Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: It has occurred to me then that, with only one observation, I cannot hope to have a covariance matrix. However, the task still remains: I have a very high-dimensional vector (a bag-of-words representation of a document) and I want to reduce its dimensions in order to be able to compute similarities between itself and other, similar vectors. So it's only one observation, but has thousands of features. Would you happen to be able to suggest something? Thanks.

Comment: Well that seems to be worthy of an entirely new question. I'm not experienced with machine learning at all, but my first thought is, if you're comparing documents, maybe a word frequencies vector (with a row for every word that appears in any document). At this point though you need to find a domain relevant way to encode the information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the option `row_var=0` in [`numpy.cov`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html):

```
In [1]: a = array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [2]: np.cov(a)
Out[2]: array(1.6666666666666667)

In [3]: np.cov(a.T)
Out[3]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [4]: np.cov(a.T, rowvar=0)
Out[4]: array(1.6666666666666667)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Not really, shouldn't that be returning a matrix of size 4 x 4? I mean, the vector has 4 "features", so given that I want to measure the variance between the features and store them in appropriate places, I need a covariance matrix.

Since you only have one observation, you can't compute a covariance matrix. Depending on the estimator the covariances would either be zero or undefined.

If that's not intuitively clear, try answering the following questions:

1. what is the variance of `1.0`?
2. what is the covariance of `1.0` and `2.0`?

In essence, these are the computations that you're asking `numpy.cov()` to perform.

Comment: 1) 0, there's no variance between an element and itself
2) Assuming that there are two dimensions, X and Y, and there's one observation which has X = 1.0 and Y = 2.0, then that should be still 0. But I might've understood something wrong. In any case, I'm still at a loss as to how to do PCA on this one-dimensional vector.